# Creating JPA Native Query is slow

Tags: java, performance, jakarta-ee, jpa, eclipselink

- Database: MySQL 5.1
- JPA implementation: EclipseLink
- Container: Glassfish 4
- Java: JDK 7u55

I use a native query to get results from a table of orders. Each order has a date and I want to select only by year and date. The whole method has this body.

```
    Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT COUNT(PLACED_ORDER.ID) as POCET_OBJEDNAVEK FROM PLACED_ORDER WHERE ORDERDATE IS NOT NULL AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ORDERDATE) = ?1 AND extract(DAY FROM ORDERDATE) = ?2");
    query.setParameter(1, year);
    query.setParameter(2, day);

    return (Long) query.getSingleResult();
```

This query **WORKS** properly, but is very slow to execute. By slow, I mean a second or more for every method call. Transaction management is set do Required.

Named queries are executed within few milliseconds, measured from request to response. Calling this method alone is very slow. Is there something that can be done about it ?

EDIT - Reaction to comments:

When I query the database from command line or via MySQL WorkBench, the performance is normal (max a millisecond or a few under heavy load).

I should also metion that **SECOND LEVEL CACHE** is **disabled** on the project and there is nothing I can do about it.

MySQL Explain looks like this (there is no easy way for me to enable explain on EclipseLink).

[image]

Entity annotations used to determine data type and DB constraints.

```
@Entity(name = "PLACED_ORDER")
public class Order implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "CUSTOMER_ID")
private Customer customer;
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.PERSIST}, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "PLACED_ORDER_ID")
private List<OrderItem> items;
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date orderDate;
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@NotNull
private OrderState orderState = OrderState.SEMIFINISHED;
@OneToOne
private Transportation transportation;
@OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, orphanRemoval = true)
private Address deliveryAddress;
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private TransportationType transportationType;
```

Comment: When you use the DBMS to execute the query you have same performance ?

Comment: Show DDL for this table, I am interested in column types

Comment: Add the execution plan for the query please

Comment: All the question I could answer are now part of the question. There is no DDL file. Project is JEE7 and annotations are used to determine data type.

Comment: is it still slow if you cache the Query?

Comment: "EclipseLink does not support the cache usage for native queries or queries that have complex result sets such as returning data or multiple objects." - So there is no way I can do it.

Comment: Native SQL returning a field doesn't hit the entity cache, but the query results themselves can be cached: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Caching/Query_Cache   You can also use a named query for the native SQL http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/Native and statement caching at the datasource/driver level to limit reparsing the statement.  See http://wiki.eclipse.org/Optimizing_the_EclipseLink_Application_(ELUG) for more performance and monitoring options.

Comment: Defining the native query as a @NamedNativeQuery instead of putting the query string directly into the createNativeQuery method solved the problem. Everything runs fast and smooth. Thank you, Chris !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With technologies specified in the question and second level cache disabled, the solution was to write the native query as **@NamedNativeQuery**, instead of creating it every time method was called. This way, the performance significantly increased.